# duplicate symbol after removing pod in xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I had a Pod and I removed it.
I ran pod install and I can now see that there are no dependencies in my project.

I added the classes manually but now project does not build.

Error is a duplicate symbol :

```
Duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CBZSplashView._iconStartSize in:
  ...../Objects-normal/x86_64/CBZSplashView.o
  ...../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-Ski Greece.a(CBZSplashView.o)
```

Why the libPods is linked?

EDIT : Could it be because the podfile is empty?

If I remove my dependency and run pod install I see this :

```
Downloading dependencies
Generating Pods project
Unable to open stream!
Integrating client project

[!] [!] The Podfile does not contain any dependencies.
```

And the derivedData/libPods.a is not created again - it has an earlier date.

Comment: Look at a build report in Xcode's Report Navigator and expand the "link" line.  The full link command should show what it's being told to include.  (Also, if it's really gone from the build settings, try deleting derived data for the project.)

Comment: @PhillipMills How can I find from where is being told to be included? Why the libPods is included after removing it from the podfile?

Comment: Ummm...I told you what I would do to start figuring it out.  (It's hard for me to magically look inside your project from way over here.  :) )

Comment: @PhillipMills can you check my edit?